# Function that returns array with odd numbers and null

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've a task to write function that returns the average value of even numbers from an array. If there are no even numbers in the array, return null.
Here are arrays and expected result:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] - should return "4" and
[1,1,1,1] - should return "null".
Where shall I put condition for null?I've tried different options but nothing works but maybe my code is wrong.

```js
function getEvenAverage(array) {
    const even = array.filter(function (element) {
        return element % 2 === 0
    });
        const sum = even.reduce(function (sum, element) {
            return (sum + element);
        });
        return sum / even.length;
}
const result1 = getEvenAverage([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
console.log(result1);
const result2 = getEvenAverage([1,1,1,1])
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Check the length of the filtered array?

Comment: One line change in your code: `return even && even.length ? sum / even.length : null;` --> please try and share your feedback if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in 1 loop as well:

#### Logic:

- Create an object(say `map`) to hold values
- Loop on array.
- Check if current item is even, compute total and length. Set it to `map`
- At the end, check for length and return value

```js
function getEvenAverage(array) {
  const map = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item % 2 === 0) {
      return { total: acc.total + item, length: acc.length + 1 }
    }
    return acc
  }, { total: 0, length: 0 });
  return map.length ? map.total / map.length : null
}
const result1 = getEvenAverage([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
console.log(result1);
const result2 = getEvenAverage([1, 1, 1, 1])
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: @jsN00b Its a bad convention. `reduce` is a part of functional programming. Your loop return 2 different types of value based on condition. So as a reader, I had to read through line by line to understand and process it. Try implementing this in typescript and you will realise the pain in your approach. So I'll rollback the change. You can add another answer, if you wish to

Comment: _Your loop return 2 different types of value based on condition_ --> exactly matching what your `function` returns based on conditions. :-) Good luck buddy.

Comment: @jsN00b My `.reduce` returns an object of type `{ total: number, length: number }`, and my function returns type `number | null`. However, for any iteration, my reduce will always return same type. My function has a conditional return but that is requirement. So if I move reduce to another function, it will always return same type. Hope I was able to address your query.

Comment: And in the **EDIT** that was added the `.reduce` returned what exactly, in your opinion, Rajesh :-). It also returned the same object "acc" on each iteration. And the "acc" object had 3 props - while yours has 2. As stated on my edit - it used the exact same logic as yours. :-). No worries mate. Have posted a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
  function getEvenAverage (arr) {
  let temp = [];
  let sum = 0;
  let count = 0;
  arr.map(item => {
    if(item % 2 === 0) {
      temp = [...temp, item]
    }
  })
  temp.map(item => {
    sum += item;
    count +=1;
  })
  if(temp.length ===0) {
    return null
  }
  return sum/count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following changes:

1. Add `null` as an initial value for [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
2. Check if `sum === null` return `sum`, otherwise calculate an average value

You can find the code with changed applied below

```js
function getEvenAverage(array) {
    const even = array.filter(function (element) {
        return element % 2 === 0
    });
    const sum = even.reduce(function (sum, element) {
        return (sum + element);
    }, null);
    return sum === null ? sum : sum / even.length;
}

const result1 = getEvenAverage([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
console.log(result1);
const result2 = getEvenAverage([1,1,1,1])
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally posted as a simple edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360899/13658816). Reposting as a separate answer below (as the other answer-er, [Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh) rolled back & noted that this be posted separately).

Added comments as this is now posted as a separate answer.

```js
// method to get average of even numbers in array
const getEvenAverage = (arr) => (
  arr                         // use optional-chainging "?." to handle bad "arr" values
  ?.reduce(                   // iterate over the array 
    (acc, itm, idx) => {      // access "acc" (accumulator), "itm" and "idx"
      if (itm % 2 === 0) {    // if itm is even number
        acc.tot += itm;       // add it to "acc" total (ie, "tot" prop)
        acc.len++;            // increment the "len" prop of "acc" 
      };
      if (                    // if processing last "itm"
        idx === arr.length - 1 &&
        acc.len > 0           // and have previously processed even number "itm"
      ) {                     // update "result" prop of "acc"
        acc.result = acc.tot / acc.len;
      };
      return acc;             // return the updated "acc" for each iteration
    },                        // initialize "acc" to have three props
    { tot: 0, len: 0, result: null }
  )                           // simply send the "result" back to the caller
  ?.result
);

console.log(
  'call fn with array: 1,2...7\naverage-of-even-numbers: ',
  getEvenAverage([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
);
console.log(
  'call fn with array: 1,1,1,1\naverage-of-even-numbers: ',
  getEvenAverage([1, 1, 1, 1])
);
console.log(
  'call fn with empty-array: []\naverage-of-even-numbers: ',
  getEvenAverage([])
);
console.log(
  'call fn with undefined: \naverage-of-even-numbers: ',
  getEvenAverage()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```